# PhoneGap iOS Low Latency Audio

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, cordova

Until PhoneGap 1.6 was released I was using a PG plugin called SoundPlug to achieve low latency audio on my iOS app project.

With PhoneGap 1.6 the SoundPlug plugin no longer works (at least I can't seem to get it too).  Does anyone have a solution I could use?

I'm using it to play a beep when a button is pressed that records audio.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins need to be updated to be used in the newly renamed Cordova.

There is a Plugin Update Guide pdf file in the .dmg file that has the iOS installer in it.

That might be a good place to start... otherwise, you might have to wait until someone updates the plugin. When they do, it will probably go into the new repo folder for iOS updated plugins (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I did exactly that. I managed to update a plugin called PG Low Latency Audio using the supplied guide and it's working great.

Comment: @nicktones: Do you have a link to the new plugin? I'm trying to do the same thing and am having trouble.

Comment: Hi, I just used the plugin update guide in the phonegap package to update the existing plugin